# unexpected rbind.fill behavior when combining columns of different class

Tags: r, plyr, rbind

I tried to use the rbind.fill function from the plyr package to combine two dataframes with a column *A*, which contains only digits in the first dataframe, but (also) strings in the second dataframe. Reproducible example:

```
data1 <- data.frame(A=c(11111,22222,33333), b=c(4444,444,44444), c=c(5555,66666,7777))
data2 <- data.frame(A=c(1234,"ss150",123456), c=c(888,777,666))
rbind.fill(data1,data2)
```

This produced the output below with incorrect data in column *A*, row 4,5,6. It did not produce an error message.

```
        A     b     c
1  107778 33434     6
2 1756756     4     7
3 2324234     5     8
4       2    NA 14562
5       3    NA 45613
6       1    NA    14
```

I had expected that the function would coerce the whole column into character class, or at least display NA or a warning. Instead, it inserted digits that I do not understand (in the actual file, these are two digit numbers that are not sorted). The [documentation](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/plyr/docs/rbind.fill) does not specify that columns must be of the same type in the to-be-combined data.frames.

How can I get this combination?

```
       A     b     c
1  11111  4444  5555
2  22222   444 66666
3  33333 44444  7777
4   1234    NA   888
5  ss150    NA   777
6 123456    NA   666
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at `class(data2$A)`. It's a factor which is actually an integer with a label vector. Use stringsAsFactors=F in your data.frame creation or in `read.csv` and friends. This will force the variables be either numeric or character vectors.

```
data1 <- data.frame(A=c(11111,22222,33333), b=c(4444,444,44444), c=c(5555,66666,7777))
data2 <- data.frame(A=c(1234,"ss150",123456), c=c(888,777,666), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

rbind.fill(data1,data2)
```

Comment: Thank you, very helpful! I used stringsAsFactors (begins with small letter, btw) in the read.csv import and now it works.

(Every time I think I understood a bit more of the different classes in R, something like this happens and I know I need to read more .. thank you for your help!)